# Android Firebase Database - Retrieving data

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing an Android app that uses Firebase database.

```
"posts": [
    {
      "post_id": 100,
      "post_kind": "V"
    },
    {
      "post_id": 100,
      "post_kind": "S"
    },
    {
      "post_id": 100,
      "post_kind": "S"
    }
]
```

I want query select all post where post_kind = S

I'm using query

```
databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference("posts");
query = databaseReference.orderByChild("post_kind").equalTo("S");
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
      @Override
      public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
          if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    List<Post> list = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        Post post = (Post) snapshot.getValue(Post.class);
                        list.add(post);
                    }
                }
            }

     @Override
     public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
           Log.e("DatabaseError", databaseError.toString());
     }
});
```

But not result

Comment: The query you've tried looks ok. What is the result you got?

Comment: you need to declare your list outside of the listener

Comment: post your `Post` class along with question

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference("posts");
query = databaseReference.orderByChild("post_kind").equalTo("S");
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
      @Override
      public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
          if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                   int postId = snapshot.child("post_id").getValue();
                   String postKind = snapshot.child("post_kind").getValue();
                }
            }
        }

      @Override
      public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
          Log.e("DatabaseError", databaseError.toString());
       }
});
```

Comment: pc_0 - Using an unspecified index. Consider adding '".indexOn": "post_kind"' at posts to your security and Firebase Database rules for better performance

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
Query query = rootRef.child("posts").orderByChild("post_kind").equalTo("S");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        List<Post> list = new ArrayList<>();

        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Post post = ds.getValue(Post.class);
            list.add(post);
        }

        Log.d("TAG", list.toString);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.e("DatabaseError", databaseError.toString());
    }
};
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```